# How to pass a variable from template to views in django?

Tags: html, django, view, jinja2

### `index.html`

```html
{% if request.session.visitor_language == 'en'  %}
                                
   {% with current_page=request.resolver_match.url_name %} 
       {{current_page}}    
   {% endwith %}

   My name is  Khan <a style="color: blue;" href="{% url 'change_language' %}?current_page={{current_page}}">BN</a>
{% endif %}
```

> Here I am trying to send the value of **current_page** to views through `urls`

### `urls.py`

```py
path('home/change_lang/$', views.change_visitor_language, name='change_language'),
```

### `views.py`

```py
def change_visitor_language(request,current_page):
    print(current_page)
```

### The Error I am getting from Screen

> TypeError at /home/change_lang/$

### The Error I am getting in command line

> TypeError: change_visitor_language() missing 1 required positional argument: 'current_page'

Comment: If you are sending Values from screen to Views.py , I would suggest you to send it through a FORM and get it through the POST method . For your scenario you can directly generate the ( request.resolver_match.url_name ) value from your views instead of sending it from a template...

Comment: I know.... but in my case from view it changes the pages. when it is in template it has a page. I need this page. So before change  the page i need to pass the pages to views so that I will redirect back to the previous page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending `current_page` as a `query param` it will not be added as a method argument to the view.

You can access it in your view like this:

```py
def change_visitor_language(request):
    current_page = request.GET.get('current_page')
```

Also, change your `HTML` like this

```
{% if request.session.visitor_language == 'en'  %}
                                
   {% with current_page=request.resolver_match.url_name %} 
       {{current_page}}    
       My name is  Khan <a style="color: blue;" href="{% url 'change_language' %}?current_page={{current_page}}">BN</a>
   {% endwith %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: vai..... it returns empty string when change view like this.

Comment: Try printing `request.GET`. My hypothesis is that it will have a key `current_page` but it will have an empty value.

I have updated my answer to accommodate those changes.